# Accessing Latitude and Longitude Android Google API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services, latitude-longitude, google-geocoding-api

I'm making an app that will be able to access and use the user's latitude and longitude to display nearby restaurants.

I was trying to retrieve the latitude and longitude variables from the onConnected(Bundle bunle) method, as shown below, to access and use them in the onCreate() method, but the String latitude I declared at the top wont store the latitude value when I set it to equal the users latitude on the onConnnected() method. I tried to test what the result will be when I displayed the String on a toast message, but the toast was just blank, indicating that the string had not been set to equal the latitude value. However, if I try displaying the toast within the scope of the onConnected() method, it works. But I really need to access this latitude and longitude outside of the onConnected() method, in the onCreate() method.

I have posted the code below! Any help will be appreciated!

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

protected static final String TAG = "Gokul Log Message: ";
protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
protected Location mLastLocation;
protected TextView textLatitude;
public String mLat = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textLatitude = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textLatitude);

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, mLat, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    buildGoogleApiClient();

}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(){
    Log.v("Log1", "Entering buildGoogleApiClient method");

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
}
@Override
protected void onStart(){
    Log.v("Log1", "Entering onStart() method");

    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
@Override
protected void onStop(){
    Log.v("Log1", "Entering onStop() method");

    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Log.v("Log1", "Entering onConnected() method");


    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null){
        textLatitude.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
       //textLongitude.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
        mLat = String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
        Log.v("Log1onConnected", mLat + "asd");
    }

    Log.v("Log1onConnected2", mLat + "asd");

}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {


    Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't changed because it doesn't have a location yet.  Just because you connect to google play doesn't mean that a location is ready.  You need to listen for location updates and set the value in onLocationChanged.

Comment: Hi Gabe! I think we have a misunderstanding let me rephrase the question. Im aware that it wont get me constant location updates, but the current code will get me one, static, unchanging latitude value that I had set to equal the string mLat. When I try to show this value on a toast, the string wont appear at all. Its not an issue of location updates, its that the string wont store the value for the latitude at all. does that make sense? Would be great if I could get help on this :)

Comment: The phone doesn't always know its location.  It doesn't keep track in the background if nobody is actively requesting updates.  When you ask it for getLastLocation, that function will only return a good value if some app was recently getting updates.  If not, it won't have one and returns null.  That's what you're seeing here.

Comment: But when I set the text of the textveiw to equal the latitude within the onConnected() method, it displays the latitude perfectly. But it wont let me access the string that I had set to equal the latitude outside of the onConnected() method. Im asking if theres any way to access the latitude as a string outside of that function, like on the onCreate() method, where I have a toast to equal the latitude?

Comment: Sure, you can save the value to a class level variable.  But onConnected is asynchronous-  it won't be called until long after onCreate is finished.  That's why its a callback functiom, otherwise the connect call would just return true or false for connection status.

Comment: thank you! could you maybe go into a bit more detail on how I could do that? Right now im trying to save the latitude value from onConnected to a string that I can then show as a toast from the  onCreate() method. Is there a way of doing that? Im new to android so bear with me :) thanks a lot!

Comment: Don't show the toast in onCreate-  do it in the onConnected function.  This isn't an android thing, its a general mutlithreading thing.  Connecting to google services is going to cause a network request, which takes time.  So it happens on another thread  While that's happening, your app continues, so onCreate finishes.  When the request is done, onConnected is called.  Since you don't set the value of the string until then, you obviously can't use it yet.